# Cannot change UIView frame size

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, frame, cgrect

I have a custom uiview that i am trying to update the frame size. I do it like this in a method once it is clicked.  The method is called, and the frame value changes, however on the screen nothing happens!

```
if (!touched) {

        GameBox *box = (GameBox *)[self.view viewWithTag:40];

        [box setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 73)];
        NSLog(@"%f", box.frame.origin.x);
        markButton.enabled = NO;
        guessButton.enabled = NO;
        [self.view reloadInputViews];

        NSLog(@"The action bar should now be hidden");
    }
    else if (touched) {
        guessButton.enabled = YES;
        markButton.enabled = YES;
        [self.view reloadInputViews];
        NSLog(@"The action bar should now be visible");
    }
```

Comment: Please ask what you want to do..so I can understand..

Comment: I want to:  a)  resize the cgrect frame of the uisubview box, and b)  disable/reenable the guess button and mark button

Answer (score 13):

I guess you have hooked self.view to UIView in `Interface Builder`.

In order to change UIView frame, in `Interface Builder` go to `File Inspector`, and uncheck `Use Autolayout`, then in the code change the frame.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't believe I spent 3 hours debugging...Thank you!

Comment: This works but it affects the ability to use autolayout for the whole document...

Comment: You can simply set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES; on the uiView element and still keep your autolayout. This will redraw the element to new frame.

Answer (score 11):

You need to set adjust the frame in the viewDidAppear (not viewDidLoad).

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
frame.origin.y += 100.0;
frame.size.height -= 100.0;
self.tableView.frame = frame;
}
```

Apparently this has something to do with table views within navigation controllers.

Answer (score 3):

It is because of Auto Layout, however you could do it after Auto Layout done its work or change constraints of it. If you want to do it after auto layout add following.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        box.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 73)];
});
```

Comment: It helped me, Thanks, but can you tell me reason why you put it inside dispatch block @Deniz

Comment: It seems that I had wanted frame size to be changed after current repaint cycle, some time after viewDidAppear method finished executing. But I am not sure now.

Answer (score -1):

`[self.view reloadInputViews]` is generally used for FirstResponders. I Don't have much of an idea about your customview, but I think for just settings the frame you can use:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

viewFrame.frame=frame;//Frame Defined by you 
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

can give better solution if i get a look at your custom view.